# Browser does not use utf-8 but meta tag is set

Tags: html, browser, utf-8, character-encoding

This is my page header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
...
```

As you can see the charset is set to utf-8 but Chrome/Firefox does not print the page as utf-8. I guess that is because the server sends this header:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15
```

How can I overwrite this header from my html page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

HTTP headers have priority over meta elements that claim to be equivalent.

Fix your server settings so it sends the correct content-type.

Answer (score 1):

You can't overwrite the charset from your html page. Things to look for:

1. Your web server may be configured with a default charset. See if you can change it. Be warned: this may be a global setting that would affect all files of a specific `Content-Type`.
2. Despite the fact that you've literally typed `charset=UTF-8` into your html document, your IDE/text editor may still be saving it with a different character encoding. If your using *nix, you can check the file encoding on any file on the command line like this:

   ```
   file -I filename.html
   ```

   If the output of that command reports something other than `UTF-8` or `us-ascii`, you should go back to your IDE/text editor and figure out how to set the character encoding on the files it saves as `UTF-8`. Your web server may be auto detecting the character encoding and setting headers accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the server header by adding an .htaccess file containing:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```